# ASP.NET WebHookReceiver "return HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized" returns HTML instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks

I'm developing a webhook receiver for an external tool.

I’m using ASP.NET WebHooks framework (more : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/ )

Everything is working great, except one thing : I can’t return a HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.

This is a structure of code in WebHookReceiver :

```
public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(string id, HttpRequestContext context, HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            try
            {
                var authheader = request.Headers.Authorization;
                if (authheader == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(authheader.Parameter))
                {
                    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                }
```

I was expecting a simple HTTP response with the code HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized (Side note, ANY other Http code works as expected). Instead it returns the whole HTML Microsoft login page. I don’t even know where it’s taking it from.

[image: The HTML page returned]

My solution for now is just returning “BadRequest” and message “Authorization failed”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.

This is perfectly normal.

https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge
>   applicable to the requested resource.

For my case, I should use 403 Forbidden